# PHP Can't Update Picklist with Existing Value

Tags: picklist, rest, php, update

I'm having a very strange problem with PHP (Laravel with Forrest) and updating values.

I've got a pick list called `Approved_Rejected__c` with the following values:

- New
- Submitted
- Approved
- Rejected

And am using the following call to update said picklist:

```
'Approved_Rejected__c'  => 'Approved',
```

Weirdly that doesn't work and only provides a

> Salesforce Response Error

However, when I try the following:

```
'Approved_Rejected__c'  => 'Something Random',
```

It works and:

```
 'Approved_Rejected__c'  => '\'Approved\'', Works
```

Works, albeit with apostrophies around the word Approved.

It seems like the picklist is only accepting values that don't exist within the Picklist, but if I try a value that does exist there's a generic and unhelpful error.

I feel like I'm missing something simple but can't quite figure out where or why.

**Edit** I've tested the exact same thing against a different Picklist field and it worked, leading me to think it's something to do with the Picklist field itself.

It's not set to:

> Strictly enforce picklist values

And Field Level Security is set to Visible, but not Read only so that all looks good.

Comment: What is the error(Salesforce Response Error)?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Part of the headache is that it isn't that descriptive. Alls I'm getting is: `[status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request` alongside said `Salesforce Response Error`. I can only assume the bad request is updating a field with an existing value, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. I tried updating the field to "Rejected" and it worked, so then within Salesforce I tried to update it to "Approved" and got a long error regarding a Trigger. Looks like that's been the main problem all along.